# Issue with loading and using NPM Modernizr v3.x Package

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modernizr

I've downloaded the `NPM` package for `modernizr` version 3.3.1 into my `Angular1` app and have it referenced correctly. However at runtime I get the following error:

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined" modernizr.js:1
```

So I thought maybe I needed `require.js` as indicated here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36986916/410937) but this didn't fix the issue.

Previously I had version 2.8.3 of `modernizr` that I had installed from `NuGet`. I know the versions are different but so are the `.js` files. Here is the new 3.3.1 version in it's entirety from the `node_modules` directory that I deploy:

```
define(['ModernizrProto'], function(ModernizrProto) {
  // Fake some of Object.create so we can force non test results to be non "own" properties.
  var Modernizr = function() {};
  Modernizr.prototype = ModernizrProto;

  // Leak modernizr globally when you `require` it rather than force it here.
  // Overwrite name so constructor name is nicer :D
  Modernizr = new Modernizr();

  return Modernizr;
});
```

The 2.8.3 version of `modernizr.js` I used was a *huge* `.js` file (~1400 lines) with apparently all the functionality within. Here are the 1st few lines to give an idea:

```
window.Modernizr = (function( window, document, undefined ) {

    var version = '2.8.3',

    Modernizr = {},

    /*>>cssclasses*/
    // option for enabling the HTML classes to be added
    enableClasses = true,
    /*>>cssclasses*/

    docElement = document.documentElement,
```

Obviously I missing some key `js` piece here about either how `modernizr` works or how to now properly load it in v3.x. What am I doing incorrectly with `modernizr`?

Comment: Are you using the `Modernizr.js` from the `src` directory?  I believe you may just want the one from the root of the directory.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @R.A.Lucas - yes you are correct. I'm using the one from the `src` directory. I checked *all* sub directories in `node_modules`. There wasn't a `modernizr.js` at the root or any other directory. However, I believe you might be on to something. Some where else I should look?

Comment: Looks like you just need to run this from the modernizr directory: `./bin/modernizr -c lib/config-all.json` and that will create the modernizr.js file.  Here's the documentation here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/modernizr.  Best.